# Extra items in JSON data when using Web API

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have a problem with the JSON data from the Web API service.

In a regular Web API Controller, I get the result given below.

```js
[
  {
    "title": "başlık",
    "description": "Tanımlama",
    "creationTime": "2018-01-15T17:20:06.9801797",
    "state": 0,
    "assignedPersonId": "afd46520-521d-4945-a4ee-083893e1d14c",
    "assignedPersonName": "derya",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "title": "title",
    "description": "description",
    "creationTime": "2018-01-15T17:17:26.5161288",
    "state": 0,
    "assignedPersonId": null,
    "assignedPersonName": null,
    "id": 1
  }
]
```

But when using ASP.NET Boilerplate infrastructure, I get the same data as:

```js
{
  "result": {
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "başlık",
        "description": "Tanımlama",
        "creationTime": "2018-01-15T17:20:06.9801797",
        "state": 0,
        "assignedPersonId": "afd46520-521d-4945-a4ee-083893e1d14c",
        "assignedPersonName": "derya",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "title": "title",
        "description": "description",
        "creationTime": "2018-01-15T17:17:26.5161288",
        "state": 0,
        "assignedPersonId": null,
        "assignedPersonName": null,
        "id": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "targetUrl": null,
  "success": true,
  "error": null,
  "unAuthorizedRequest": false,
  "__abp": true
}
```

It seems that the actual raw data is nested in an outer data structure. Because of this, deserialization like below doesn't work.

```js
List<Class1> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(JSONString);
```

And I have to manage some string operations on `JSONString`.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation on [WrapResult and DontWrapResult Attributes](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Javascript-API/AJAX#wrapresult-and-dontwrapresult-attributes):

> You can control wrapping using **WrapResult** and **DontWrapResult** attributes for an action or all actions of a controller.
>
> #### ASP.NET MVC Controllers
>
> ASP.NET Boilerplate **wraps** ASP.NET MVC action results **by default** if return type is **JsonResult** (or Task<JsonResult> for async actions). You can change this by using **WrapResult** attribute as shown below:
>
> ```cs
> public class PeopleController : AbpController
> {
>     [HttpPost]
>     [WrapResult(WrapOnSuccess = false, WrapOnError = false)]
>     public JsonResult SavePerson(SavePersonModel person)
>     {
>         // TODO: save new person to database and return new person's id
>         return Json(new {PersonId = 42});
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> As a shortcut, we can just use **[DontWrapResult]** which is identical for this example.
>
> You can change this default behaviour from startup configuration.

This applies not only to ASP.NET MVC Controllers, but also to ASP.NET Web API Controllers, Dynamic Web API Layer and ASP.NET Core Controllers.

Comment: You are really good at Aspnetboilerplate..and I think I should read the documentation carefully ..thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Aaron for such a wonderful clean answer.

@Inanc, If you can map this JSON response with the below-mentioned class also.

**JSON:**

```
{
  "result": {
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "başlık",
        "description": "Tanımlama",
        "creationTime": "2018-01-15T17:20:06.9801797",
        "state": 0,
        "assignedPersonId": "afd46520-521d-4945-a4ee-083893e1d14c",
        "assignedPersonName": "derya",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "title": "title",
        "description": "description",
        "creationTime": "2018-01-15T17:17:26.5161288",
        "state": 0,
        "assignedPersonId": null,
        "assignedPersonName": null,
        "id": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "targetUrl": null,
  "success": true,
  "error": null,
  "unAuthorizedRequest": false,
  "__abp": true
}
```

**Code:**

```
public class Item
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime creationTime { get; set; }
    public int state { get; set; }
    public string assignedPersonId { get; set; }
    public string assignedPersonName { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
    public object targetUrl { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
    public bool unAuthorizedRequest { get; set; }
    public bool __abp { get; set; }
}
```

**Deserialization Code:**

```
List<RootObject> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(JSONString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines to the `PreInitialize()` method of your `Web.Core` project module (`<ProjectName>WebCoreModuleModule.cs`): [docs](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Javascript-API/AJAX#wrapresult-and-dontwrapresult-attributes)

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpAspNetCore().DefaultWrapResultAttribute.WrapOnError = false;
Configuration.Modules.AbpAspNetCore().DefaultWrapResultAttribute.WrapOnSuccess = false;
```